# Highcharts spline chart, display summed by week, month?

Tags: highcharts

I have a spline chart with daily data. My data is in daily ticks. Is it possible, to make HC show the data in weekly or monthly ticks, instead of the daily ones? The grouped data by week/month should be the sum of the past 7/30 days, not the average.

Or I have to manually pre-process it before feeding it to HC?

EDIT: Main chart config:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    'chart':{
    'renderTo':'container',
    'type':'spline',
    'zoomType':'x'
},
```

JS Fiddle with example chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/gqWLU/

Answer (score 2):

We tried a Hack around this, where we used Highstock's (Splinechart) [RangeSelector](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector), Event and [DataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping). On click of weekly rangeselectorButton we catch this event through [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes). Post catching the event approximate it to "sum". If you are using two series than iterate the object.

```
  events: {
         setExtremes: function (e) {
             if (e.rangeSelectorButton != undefined) {
                 var triger = e.rangeSelectorButton;
                 if (triger.type == 'week') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['week', [1]];
                     });
                 } else if (triger.type == 'day') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['day', [1]];
                     });
                 }
             }
         }
     },
```

Comment: This is a duplicate [of an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29534469/472495) you posted 10 minutes prior to this one. Please don't copy-and-paste answers across questions - if you think they are duplicates, please add a comment under the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the **[`plotOptions.spline.dataGrouping.approximation`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.spline.dataGrouping.approximation)** option available in Highstock and set it use to "sum" for approximation and set the data grouping to 1 week. Unfortunately, I don't think such a feature is available in core Highcharts though.

**Code**

```
dataGrouping: {
        approximation: "sum",
        enabled: true,
        units: [[
            'week',
            [1]
            ]]
    }
```

**[Data grouping/aggregating | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/UEXAG/)**