# Data Grouping - Monthly (end-of-month)

Tags: highcharts

I'm having a very difficult time trying to get my data to be grouped via month. I've even gone so far as to programmatically filter through my data to return only the last day of the month and calculate the monthly value. I've tried to find a good explanation on the 'dataGrouping' property but have had no luck understanding it nor properly implementing it. Every results returns my series in a daily interval.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a minimum number of data points needed for data grouping to
   work?
2. Under the [dataGrouping.units](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.units) I've tried to use this
   documentation but nothing has worked for me - Still results in a
   daily interval - Could someone explain this for me?

Any help on this would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using HighStock graph?

If yes...

Sure, it takes a lot of data to get grouping. If datagrouping option is enabled, Highstock handle automatically the switch between every grouping mode. So if you don't have a lot of data, it will not work with default settings

So, if you want to group by default, you need to force the grouping.

```
series:[{
    [...]
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: "sum",
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            units: [['month',[1]]]

        }
}]
```

**EDIT**

Here is a working example demo (fork of a basic highstock demo) 
http://jsfiddle.net/NcNvu/

Hope it helps!
Regards

Comment: I'm assuming the: units: [['month' , [1]] where 1 is equal to the number of months to group?

Comment: @Scott yes, take look at this: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.units

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Just out of curiosity, would any one happen to know the minimum # of datapoints required for data grouping to work?

Answer (score 1):

We tried a Hack around this, where we used Highstock's (Splinechart) [RangeSelector](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector), Event and [DataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping). On click of weekly rangeselectorButton we catch this event through [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes). Post catching the event approximate it to "sum". If you are using two series than iterate the object. Currently doing it weekly just extend it for Monthly using corresponding UNIT

```
  events: {
         setExtremes: function (e) {
             if (e.rangeSelectorButton != undefined) {
                 var triger = e.rangeSelectorButton;
                 if (triger.type == 'week') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['week', [1]];
                     });
                 } else if (triger.type == 'day') {
                     $.each(this.series, function (index, obj) {
                         obj.options.dataGrouping.units[0] = ['day', [1]];
                     });
                 }
             }
         }
     },
```