# Reduce the amount of rendered datapoints in a zoomable areaspline with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a graph that will present sold entrance tickets over a quarter with a granularity of 1 datapoint per hour.

To make this presentable, I am using highcharts zoom feature together with a stacked areaspline.

My problem is that the graph gets really spiky when zoomed out, since it has to render a lot of datapoints that could fluctuate between a few hundred to zero in an hour or two, so I am wondering if there is a way to limit the amount of rendered datapoints per x-axis tick, to smooth the spline out further?

An example would be if the x-axis is fully zoomed out, it would label the months and render 4 datapoints per month, when I then zoom in on the beginning of say July, it would label first of july through fourth of july and render 4 datapoints per day.

BR Fredrik

Comment: try data grouping if you are using highstock

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596292/data-grouping-monthly-end-of-month

Comment: Maybe [lazy-loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) solution will be convenient for you ?